# Python: Checking whether a certain shapekey exists at active mesh

Tags: python

I want to check whether a certain shapekey exists at the active mesh. How can I do that?

(Background: I have written a script, which dumps all shapekeys of a mesh with the associated values into a a textfile. Another scripts reads this files and assigns the values back to another mesh of a newer version. If the set of defined shapekeys changes, the latter scripts fails with
"shapekey not found". I want to check for this case beforehand)

Comment: You mean check for a shapekey with a certain name?

Comment: yes...exactly :)

Answer (score 4):

**Using `get`**

Another way than testing if the name is in the collection keys, is to use get.  If an object has shapekeys then

```
sk = ob.shape_keys.key_blocks.get("Foo")
```

will return the shapekey named "Foo" if it exists, else None.

Similarly to a poll method, can make a helper method and pass it the object and the shapekey name.

```
def has_shape_key(ob, name):
    return bool(
        hasattr(ob.data, "shape_keys")
        and ob.data.shape_keys
        and ob.data.shape_keys.key_blocks.get(name)
        )
```

Can string ands together in a python expression the first one to "fail" *ie* is False will abort further evaluating the expression and return False.

Comment: Thank you for the solution this and the other one are both valid for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can test whether a collection has an item named `'foo'` with `'foo' in collection`. So

```py
def active_object_has_keyblock(name):
    ob = bpy.context.active_object
    if not ob or ob.type != 'MESH':
        return False

    mesh = ob.data
    if not mesh.shape_keys:
        return False

    return name in mesh.shape_keys.key_blocks
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution this and the other one are both valid for me.